# Bundling external files to be used by multiple modules using webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am building modules which will be installed in a project. They have similar dependencies which causes packaging of dependencies multiple times in bundle using webpack. So I made dependencies as external.

For eg:

```
external: {
    'react':'react',
    'react-dom':'react-dom'
}
```

But now I am struggling to find a way to bundle the dependencies into a common js file which can be used with modules.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format for externals config in your webpack:

```
// Exclude React from the bundle, must be react and react-dom here otherwise will not be excluded
externals: {
  react: {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react',
    umd: 'react',
  },
  'react-dom': {
    root: 'ReactDOM',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom',
    umd: 'react-dom',
  },
},
```

And you can include and use the all the externals libraries in your main (top) application.

Not sure if that's your scenario. Could be good to know quite bit more.

Comment: I am able to make modules external, using the config I have mentioned. But the issue is I want to bundle all the external into one file, how can I do it ? 

Like including react and react-dom as another file bundled together so it can be read as external when rendering front end